# Bias Parameter in MLP in spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I am using MLP of spark mlib for predictive analysis. I want to give more weightage to one of the output class and i am using `Multilayer perceptron classifier` for prediction.  As given in the documentation here [Spark Multilayer perceptron classifier](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#multilayer-perceptron-classifier).

```
       y(x)=fK(...f2(wT2f1(wT1x+b1)+b2)...+bK)
```

Is there any give by which i can give my own bias parameter (i.e. b1, b2 etc) in above given classifier? Reason to do so is that i want to reduce the false negative. Moreover, Is this the correct way to do so?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, please review it !

Comment: @eliasah let me know what confusion do you have in my question sorry for poor explanation of problem.

Comment: I have edited the question kindly reply if you have any idea about this thanks in advance